# Woocommerce order.updated webhook not always triggered

Tags: hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am struggling with some weird issue, maybe someone has an idea how to resolve it / Automate a workaround.

When a new order is placed, woocommerce triggers order.updated hooks.

Order that has not yet been paid has status pending:
[screenshot pending order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LN7zk.png)

After the order has been paid, an API call is sent with status processing

[screenshot processing order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEixG.png)

The API on the receiver side only responds to messages with status processing.

**Issue:**

Sometimes it happens (+/- 1 time on 30 orders) that the 2nd message (status processing) is not triggered automatically.

**Workaround:** Open order manually and click update. This triggers order.updated api with status processing.

Unfortunately i am not able to catch the scenario when this happens.

As a solution I thought of some script to "retry" open orders in status processing and then put cron on it to execute every hour? I am not a developer and will not be able to create it myself..
But maybe there are other / better ideas how to resolve it?

Thank a lot!